# Distinguishing between GET and POST data in CherryPy?

Tags: python, cherrypy, web-frameworks

I've been deciding between Python web frameworks for a project of mine and I've really liked how lightweight, flexible, and concise CherryPy is compared to others. The only problem I'm having is I can't find any documentation on how to distinguish between data sent via GET and via POST.

For example, I don't want users to be able to provide their login credentials through a GET request (http://example.com/login?username=user&password=pass) but, according to [CherryPy's tutorial](http://cherrypy.org/wiki/CherryPyTutorial#ReceivingdatafromHTMLforms), all data is sent as method parameters, no matter what HTTP method they're sent as. Is there some way to say I only want the POST data or do I have to use [MethodDispatcher](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/_cpdispatch.html#cherrypy._cpdispatch.MethodDispatcher)?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note that you shouldn't assume that just because something's coming in as a POST, the user hasn't tampered with it, or that nosey people can't see it.

Comment: Be aware that discarding data sent via GET doesn't stop the user from trying to send it that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [the docs](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/refman/_cprequest.html#cherrypy._cprequest.Request.method).

> A string containing the HTTP method, such as "GET" or "POST". Set
>   in the "run" phase.

looks like checking cherrypy.request.method is what you want to do.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. It also looks like there's [a way](http://cherrypy.org/wiki/RequestObject#params) to get the data without specifying them in the method's parameters.

Comment: documentation seems to have moved to http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cprequest.html You can extract just the POST arguments with cherrypy.request.body_params